# Ошибка при создании задания SQL Server Java

Tags: java, sql-server, запрос

Cервлет должен создавать задание, но выводиться ошибка "Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "GO"
Не могу понять в чем ошибка, может кто-то увидит? Заранее спасибо

```
 public void  createJobEveryDay(String name, String command, int time)throws Exception{

        String sql = "USE [msdb] GO  BEGIN TRANSACTION  DECLARE @ReturnCode INT  SELECT @ReturnCode = 0  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'Data Collector' AND category_class=1)  BEGIN  EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'Data Collector'  IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback  END  DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)  EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N?, @enabled=1,  @notify_level_eventlog=0, @notify_level_email=0,  @notify_level_netsend=0,  @notify_level_page=0,  @delete_level=0,  @description=N'Описание недоступно', @category_name=N'Data Collector',  @owner_login_name=N'Admin', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT  IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback  EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'InputData',   @step_id=1, @cmdexec_success_code=0, @on_success_action=1,  @on_success_step_id=0,  @on_fail_action=2, @on_fail_step_id=0, @retry_attempts=1, @retry_interval=1,  @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', @command=N?,@database_name=N'FininceAnalysis', @flags=0 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Input_20-00', @enabled=1,  @freq_type=4, @freq_interval=1, @freq_subday_type=1, @freq_subday_interval=0, @freq_relative_interval=0, @freq_recurrence_factor=0, @active_start_date=20170514, @active_end_date=99991231, @active_start_time=?,@active_end_time=235959, @schedule_uid=N'4eaa82da-1313-4681-9335-d28e9b37d031' IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)' IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback COMMIT TRANSACTION  GOTO EndSave QuitWithRollback:  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  EndSave:GO";

        PreparedStatement ps = MyConnection.openConnection().prepareCall(sql);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, command);
        ps.setInt(3, time);

        ps.execute();


    }



protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try{


       createJobEveryDay("name","U",120000);

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        out.close();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GO` не является ключевым словом T-SQL, это инструкция SQL Server Management Studio позволяющая разделять выполнение отдельных конструкций в скрипте. Как и многие другие в тексте вашего запроса.

Comment: А чем его можно заменить?

Comment: Убрал конструкции  SQL Server Management Studio  и все работает, спасибо